# C# ASP.NET Core Razor page - call PageModel method from inside the Razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, razor

Here's my problem: I have a page that has 2 Select elements (dropdowns). The first selects a value, when the first selection changed I want the second dropdown to load values.

I already know that I can use the `asp-items` property to "bind" values into the dropdown.

I am trying to use the `onchange` method on the first select element and then in the JS-Script to call a method in the model to load the items.

But I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'

This is my html.cs:

```
<a>Article: </a>
<select name="Articles" id="articles" asp-for="@Model.SelectedArticleTag" asp-items="@Model.ArticlesDropdownItems">
    <option value="notChosen">Choose Article...</option>
</select>

<br/>

<a>Article Variant: </a>
<select name="ArticleVariants" id="variants" asp-items="@Model.ArticleVariantsDropdownItems">
    <option value="notChosen">Choose Variant...</option>
</select>
```

This is my html.cs Script section to get the `onchange` event: (`@Model.UpdateVariants();` shows me the error I mentioned at the top)

```
@section scripts {
<script>
    $("#articles").on("change", function () {

        @Model.UpdateVariants();
    });
</script>
}
```

And this is my PageModel method I want to call (which doesn't get called):

```
public void UpdateVariants()
{
     string articleNumber = ArticlesDropdownItems[SelectedArticleTag].Value;

     var unifiedVariants = LoadVariants(articleNumber).Result.ToList();

     ArticleVariantsDropdownItems = unifiedVariants.Select(v => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = v.ArticleVariantNumber,
            Text = $"{v.ArticleVariantNumber} - {v.ArticleVariantSize} - {v.ArticleVariantPrice}"
        }).ToList();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .cshtml page Script section, you can't directly use `@Model.UpdateVariants();` to call the handler method. And for the UpdateVariants handler method, you need to return the JsonResult, instead of use `void`.

To create a Cascading Dropdowns With AJAX in Razor Pages, you could refer the following code:

Code in the .cshtml.cs file:

```
public class CascadingDropdownsModel : PageModel
{
    private ICategoryService categoryService;
    public CascadingDropdownsModel(ICategoryService categoryService) => this.categoryService = categoryService;
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public SelectList Categories { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        //get the category data, and popuplate the first dropdown list.
        Categories = new SelectList(categoryService.GetCategories(), nameof(Category.CategoryId), nameof(Category.CategoryName));
    }
    public JsonResult OnGetSubCategories()
    {
        //based on the categoryid to find all subcategories, then return them to the view page and populate the second dropdownlist.
        return new JsonResult(categoryService.GetSubCategories(CategoryId));
    }
}
```

Code in the .csthml file:

```
@page
@model RazorAPP.Pages.CascadingDropdownsModel
<h4>Categories</h4>
<select asp-for="CategoryId" asp-items="Model.Categories">
    <option value="">Select Category</option>
</select>
<h4>SubCategories</h4>
<select asp-for="SubCategoryId"></select>

@section scripts{ 
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#CategoryId").on("change", function() {
            var categoryId = $(this).val();
            $("#SubCategoryId").empty();
            $("#SubCategoryId").append("<option value=''>Select SubCategory</option>");
            $.getJSON(`?handler=SubCategories&categoryId=${categoryId}`, (data) => {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    $("#SubCategoryId").append(`<option value="${item.subCategoryId}">${item.subCategoryName}</option>`);
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

The result like this:

[image]

More detail information, see [Cascading Dropdowns With AJAX in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/cascading-dropdowns).